# How many prime numbers in a given interval?

Tags: prime-numbers, natural-numbers, prime-gaps, interval-arithmetic

Is there any algorithm or a technique to calculate how many prime numbers lie in a given closed interval [a1, an], knowing the values of a1 and an, with a1,an ∈ ℕ?

Example:

[2, 10] --> 4 prime numbers {2, 3, 5, 7}

[4, 12] --> 3 prime numbers {5, 7, 11}

Comment: You may found this helpful. [Prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and get $\pi(a_n)-\pi(a_1-1)$

Comment: Since $a_1$ is included in the interval, I think your formula should be $\pi(a_n)-\pi(a_{1}-1)$

Comment: @paw88789: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) gives an approximation to $\pi(n),$ the number of primes less than $n$.  You can subtract the values at the start and end of an interval.  Mathematica and other software can compute exact values for small values of $n$ and approximate values for larger values of $n$.  The first approximation is $\pi(n) \sim \frac n{\log n}$ but a much better one is $$\pi(n)\sim \int_2^n \frac {dt}{\log t}$$